# WebRick. Can't shutdown the server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

My OS is Ubuntu 10.04. I started WebRick by "rails s" command. But now a can't stop him. I try to stop him using this hotkeys Ctrl + C and Ctrl +Break...but nothin helping...

Comment: That's strange. Try (in a new terminal window) doing `ps ax | grep ruby`. You'll see the process that's running. Then do a `kill -9 <process number>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it worked for the asker, I'll add my comment here as an answer for others.

Try (in a new terminal window) doing `ps ax | grep ruby`. You'll see the process that's running. Then do a `kill -9 <process number>`.